# What does "rack" mean in "rack of lamb"

Tags: meaning

The word "rack" is likely one the words with the most meanings, like "dull" or "jag".

Aside from a kind of shelf and a verb, it appears to mean something related to food. What is this meaning?

Comment: Have you done any research such as looking in a dictionary?

Comment: @BillJ yep, but rack has many meanings and I couldn't find this one in particular. The same as with the meaning of "tinker in" instead of "tinker with".

Comment: "dull" has maybe three senses (dark, boring, blunt)  "jag" is rare I can't think of any common meaning except the perhaps the sense "sharp protrusion" (It is a back formation from "jagged")  This seems to have been very easy to check with a dictionary, or perhaps google image search.

Comment: @JamesK I tried to google it and I don't have good english dictionaries around me irl. "Dull" has way more meanings than those 3 and don't get me started on "jag".

Comment: @James Here are just a couple of the meanings of jag https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/jag not to mention jag of clothes which beyonce herself used in a song and I'm pretty sure there are verb usages for that word.

Comment: The dictionary is deceiving you!  The first meaning is slang, dated and dialect (I've never heard jag used like that, so it is pretty rare).  The second is a rare Scottish variant of jab, again  rare, and informal and restricted to Scotland.  Learner won't need to know these senses.  The last is rare rather poetic and is the back form from jagged.  Now Jagged is a word you'll need to know, but not "jag".  (the other sense is "Jag" short for Jaguar motor car.)

Comment: There may be further slang meanings, and some archaic senses.  But from an English Learner's point of view, "jag" should be considered to be "not a word".

Comment: @JamesK  It might be a regionalism, but I (in the US) have definitely heard *jag* in the sense of "a short period", and [ngrams suggests that at least *crying jag* still has a lot of currency.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+*+jag&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

Comment: @stangdon - In the UK someone acting e.g. hyperactively or erratically (because of recently drinking lots of strong coffee, or maybe taking those tablets you can buy) can be said to be _on a caffeine jag_.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey jag can have way more meanings than just the three presented by Cambridge although the main ones are those pointed by James and by you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rack of lamb is made from the rib cage of the sheep.

A rack is (originally) a type of framework with bars on which you can place or hang things.  In a rack of lamb, the ribs form something that looks like a rack in the framework sense.